# xamarin.forms googlemaps infowindow click open new page

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

in my Xamarin.Forms App I have an Page which indicates an GoogleMap.
Everything is working perfect, but when I click on an InfowWindow from a pin, i cant open a new detailpage. The App hangs and I can do nothing with the App. I get no error message.

But its working in iOS.

Heres the Code:

```
private void MapObjekt_InfoWindowClicked(object sender, InfoWindowClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            App.locator.StopListeningAsync();
            App.locator.PositionChanged -= Locator_PositionChanged;

            objektliste detailPage = new objektliste();
            App.mdp.Detail = detailPage;
        }
```

Whats my fault ?

Comment: Please create a debug point in this function see if the event was triggered correctly. It could be the codes inside that crash the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, that I have to open the Page in the Mainthread like this:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { App.mdp.Detail = detailPage; });
```